# jquery mobile label wrapping checkbox generates DOM error

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating a large dynamic form and want to create checkboxes and radio buttons like:

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="myradio"><span class="foo">This is the Label</span></label>
```

This is for a number of reasons.  There's nothing wrong with this as far as HTML spec goes.

But, jquery mobile generates a DOM error for every checkbox or radio button generated this way.  It really seems to want:

```html
<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="radio1"><Label for="radio1">...</label>
```

Any workarounds? Ideas?

Comment: which version are you using? I did the same today and it worked without problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:  http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/228/edit with latest JQM

Maybe you should just swap the order of elements.